# Mediawiki running rebuildtextindex.php made phrase searches take minutes

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

I've inherited an in production mediawiki server that has had pages automatically generated by python scripts using large datasets. There are about 2 million pages on this particular wiki. We noticed that some phrase searches were not turning up any results that clearly should have. So we ran maintenance/rebuildtextindex.php like mediawiki prescribed. Now the search results are returning correctly. The issue is that words are searching fine, but phrases are not. Eg. "word1 word2" without quotes returns results in a few seconds or less, but with quotes literally takes minutes with the browser stating "waiting for [domain]..." before finally returning the results.

I've tried looking into issues with this script, the mediawiki version is 1.24, so I tried running the script with and without dropping the search index table. Both bring the same result.

I'm new to mediawiki and have enough php knowledge to understand basic php, I'm okay with SQL, but can't see what I'm missing. How can I get the phrase searches to be faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native MediaWiki uses MySQL fulltext indexing which is not really meant for billions of words (assuming a thousand words per page `"word1 word2"` will translate to a JOIN with 10^18 rows...). You should probably use a technology that was developed for search (such as ElasticSearch via the [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch) extension).